# Confused About XOR Gate

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, circuit-design, logic-gates

[image: XOR Gate from Ben Eater Video]

The image is from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTu3LwpF6XI

I'm new to digital electronics. Why is the 5V rail in the red box needed to complete the XOR gate? It seems like it might work without it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: go with your hunch and work out how the circuit would work without the 5 V rail in the red box

Comment: Assume A=1 and B=1, what is the voltage across the two first transistors.  I think it may be high enough to make the third transistor conduct just a tiny bit.

Comment: Oh ok I thought that if A and B are switched on then there wont be any current through the 3rd transistor. I guess forward voltage drop is usually only around 0.6 V. So... adding the 5V in the red box ensures there wont be current across the collector/emitter in the 3rd transistor? Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, it’s not a real RTL XOR gate as the inputs A,B cannot go above 0.7V which makes for illegal Vol low levels so the RED wire is not necessary , to cause the LED to behave in XOR fashion, but if the input has series R’s after all A,B’s then the circuit  give proper Vol=0 and full brightness when LED is ON and the pullup would give full 5V when off.

Comment: I think the power supplying the inputs (A, B) and the resistor between in the input and transistor is implied (implicit is often nothing but poor explicit though).